# Locked in an alien crypt: Jewels on the floor

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story, cryptic-clues

Dazed, you slowly regain consciousness. You don’t know how you got here, but one thing is certain – your exploration of this otherworldly planet has reached an ugly end. Trapped in an alien crypt, what hope is there of escaping? There is only one door, and in front of that lie a physically innumerable number of keys of different materials. A leaden key, a silver key, a golden key, a wooden key, a copper key, a granite key, a sapphire key, the list goes on… You know there is no time to try all of them.

But there in front of you, lying on the high-tech tiled floor, is an arrangement of jewels. Is it a message left by a previous captive indicating which key to use? Is it a test by the aliens? It may be your only clue, so you had better interpret it quickly…

- **Which key is this arrangment of jewels indicating you should try?**

---

[image: Jewels]

---

**Hint:**

> Try looking at the general shape that each of the three colours forms. Once you have done that, you will have to combine this information with the colours themselves, and see what they mean *together*...

<sub>For this simple puzzle, all you need to look at is the arrangement of the jewels. Everything else is flavour, including the aliens' high-tech grouting. A simplified image (which has all the information you need to solve the puzzle) may be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsdLp.png) (it is also annotated with the colours – red, yellow, orange – for anyone having trouble with reading them).</sub>

Comment: rot13(Ybbxf yvxr n Ibebabv Qvntenz pbzchgrq guebhtu Qrynhanl Gevnathyngvba gb zr - nalobql pner gb erirefr ratvarre gur bevtvany cbvagf?)

Comment: @Avi Not quite the right track... The image was constructed a much simpler and dirtier way.

Comment: @Avi I thought the same at first, but... there are some lines that are too straight for a Voronoi diagram (like the nearly horizontal slope in the upper right corner)

Answer (score 2):

When I

> separate out the individual jewel colours

I get

> [image: this image]

which looks like

> A red/ruby B, an orange/amber G, and a yellow 's

However I can't quite work out how to apply

> the hint to incorporate the pattern made by each colour of jewel with that colour itself - B + red = bread? BG's = Bee Gees?

Based on comments from the OP:

> The orange jewels are not intended to be a G - perhaps a C then? And the names of the colours are stated as given. So we have:
>  Bred Corange 'syellow...
>  The OP indicates that we have to make unique dictionary words, so:
>  B+RED = BRED
>  C+ORANGE = ACROGEN (a kind of moss or fern apparently)
>  'S+YELLOW = ??? OWL'S LEY? WOLLEY'S? YELLOW'S?
>  and then put these together in an order that will point to a key.... I am completely stumped at this point.

OK, more thoughts based on comments:

> So my words are confirmed to be BRED OREGANO YELLOW'S in some order.
>  The pointer to the title made me notice the phrase "ENCRYPT" inside the wording so I started trying things like Playfair en/decoding "JEWELS ON THE FLOOR" using as the keyword various combinations of "BRED OREGANO YELLOW'S", and I also tried it the other way around (en/decoding various combinations of "BRED OREGANO YELLOW'S" with the keyword "JEWELS" or "JEWELS ON THE FLOOR". However none of these attempts resulted in anything useful.

Comment: Nice work! +1. Note that I've given you the names of the colours in the question. Your identification of the yellow and red jewels is spot on, but I had a slightly different intention for the orange jewels. Your "bread" guess would be correct if red were spelt "read" - if you're more precise you'll find there's only one dictionary word possible in each case. Finally, once you've completed that step, you'll need to note that the puzzle's setting is a clue as to how to interpret what you've got to determine which key to use to open the door.

Comment: 'syellow is not an actual word though, and corange is not in most dictionaries. A little bit more tweaking is required here to get the unique words meant...

Comment: rot13(Fhccbfr gung gurer jrer jbeqf "qvoerq", "nzpbenatr", naq "baq'f lryybj" (V ernyvfr gurer nera'g bs pbhefr) naq guvf jbhyq yrnq gb zr n QV-NZ-BAQ xrl - vf gung gur glcr bs cebprff V arrq gb or sbyybjvat?)

Comment: Abg dhvgr. Whfg xrrc qbvat jung lbh'ir qbar fb sne. Lbh'ir znqr O + ERQ -> gur havdhr jbeq gung vf n pbzovangvba bs gubfr (OERQ). Abj qb gur fnzr sbe ? + BENATR naq 'F + LRYYBJ. Gurer ner havdhr nafjref. Gung fubhyq or rabhtu gb gryy snveyl rnfvyl jung gur nafjref ner. Lbh gura arrq gb chg gurfr jbeqf gbtrgure va n zrnavatshy jnl. Gurer'f bayl 6 cbffvoyr jnlf gb qb vg, fb vg fubhyqa'g or gbb uneq...

Comment: Sorry this seems to be causing more confusion than it should... Have a closer look at the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsdLp.png) I linked. Is it really a C?

Comment: Well I thought it could be a G, C, O or D, leading to (nothing), ACROGEN, OREGANO or GROANED respectively... you had said it wasn't a G and there wasn't a single unique answer for that option anyway. So from the simplified image let's take it as an O - BRED OREGANO YELLOW'S? Not helping... I feel like I'm being really dense.

Comment: O is correct and your words are correct (they're the only options with B, O, 'S). There are only 6 ways to order them into a sentence now, so find what makes some sort of grammatical sense and interpret it (the title of the puzzle may be a useful hint as to how to interpret the final sentence). I apologize for the confusion - it seems this puzzle was less obvious than I initially thought.

Comment: I've edited in some more thoughts. No apology needed - the puzzle is intriguing and "obvious" usually == "not interesting" so we're good :)

Comment: No encryption here, although the word 'crypt' is relevant. Maybe put the three words into a meaningful order first. That's the only way you'll get meaning out of them.

Comment: I have to gracefully admit defeat at this point. I have stared and stared at the list of 6 permutations of the three words and can't see any of them being more meaningful than any of the others!

Comment: I've added a tag as a hint. May also be helpful to remember that the 's suffix does not only indicate a possessive...

Comment: Dunno what you've thought of, but may also be helpful to remember that yellow can be an adjective, as well as a noun.

Comment: I've already thought of "X's" meaning "X has" / "X is", but either of those requires Yellow to be a noun. I can't think of anything where you can have "adjective's". I really think there's some critical piece of cultural knowledge I am missing that would allow me to finish solving this. I've seen the additional tag but without knowing the order of those words it doesn't help of course.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure how much to say without giving the whole thing away. I'll wait a bit before adding another hint. One particular order of the 6 can be interpreted fairly straightforwardly in light of that tag. There is some [tag:knowledge] required of course, but only what can be found through a simple Google search given that you already know the three words...

Comment: V thrff guvf znl or "Oerq bertnab lryybjf", n pelcgvp pyhr (tvira va uvag) va juvpu gur qrsvavgvba vf "lryybjf" naq gur jbeqcynl vf "oerq bertnab".  *Tbyqra* bertnab vf n fcrpvny oerrq bs lryybj bertnab, naq tbyqra pbhyq or n flabalz sbe lryybjf. Znlor. Qbrfa'g znxr zhpu frafr ohg pbhyq or pybfr? Guvf jbhyq zrna jr fubhyq hfr gur TBYQRA XRL.

Comment: Znlor jr nantenz vg gb "Oerq lryybj bertnabf" juvpu vf n fgenvtug hc qqrs sbe "TBYQRA (bertnab)"

Comment: @Amoz Sorry I was at work and not thinking straight when I made my last comment. I meant to say *You're essentially there. It's a double definition, so reordering your words should make it make more sense (remember there's an apostrophe).* To be fair at this point you're so close to the intended solution, I'd probably accept it if you posted it, although slight tweaking should make it make a bit more sense. It's a pity this puzzle has proved so fiddly to solve...

Answer (score -2):

I think that if you look at the arrangement you can see a:

> Letter G

So the answer is the:

> Golden key

Comment: Not the intended solution! Try looking a little closer. Actually not terribly far from the right track...

Comment: There could also be a granite key, a garnet key etc. in the list of possible keys. The solution method will need to give a more definite answer. I'll add some more keys to the question accordingly to eliminate simple answers like this that don't take the whole arrangement into account.